# do not allow zero using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

Allow the users to enter numeric's greater than 0 "and/or" a maximum of 2 decimal places.

**Expected Output format:**
`123.45` **or** 
`1.46` **or**
`34234.23` **or**
`34.04` **or** 
`0.33`

**not like:**
`67.6787`  **or**
`45.546.65` **or** 
`0`

Below code works fine, but it accepts '0'

```
 $('input').keyup(function () {
    if(!(/^\d+(\.{0,1}\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value)))
             this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length - 1);
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Width="50"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to avoid having the user add a leading/ending zero? You're going to have a problem actively detecting an ending zero as you won't be able to determine if the user is going to enter another digit. Your best bet here is to lop off ending zeros after the value is submitted. If you're looking for a leading zero you just need to detect the first character as being 0.

Comment: In other words, I should allow the users to enter >0.

Comment: To clarify your question are you saying this: 0.123 = invalid, 123.450 = invalid, 12.304 = valid?

Comment: it can be any numbers after period. but, the max-length is 2 after period.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to match your technical constraints. No where above do you mention a two-digit resolution although I see that in your code. I would also clearly indicate examples via "valid" and "invalid".

Comment: @D80Buckeye: modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead based regex to disallow 0 values:

```
/^(?!0(\.0*)?$)\d+(\.?\d{0,2})?$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ5rF5/4)

It will allow:

```
0.1
1.0
345.67
1.1
1.23
```

It will not allow:

```
0.
0
0.0
0.00
45.56.45
```

Comment: but this one allows 0.1 in one scenario. For Eg., Enter 1 and move your cursor before 1 and type "0."

Comment: I was wrong. Of course, .1 > 0. I will go with /^(?!0(\.0*)?$)\d+(\.{0,1}\d{0,2})?$/

Comment: In that case, /^(?!0(\.0*)?$)\d+(\.{0,1}\d{0,2})?$/  is not allowing me to enter 0.1 in a straight way

Comment: `/^(?!0(\.0*)?$)\d+(\.{0,1}\d{0,2})?$/` will allow `0.1`, check my rolledback answer and new demo.